# How to move to collide objects during the physcis simulation in blender 2.8.3?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I see this tutorial that uses blender 2.7:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROE15KY97XM

In ~18 minutes he collides a passive rigid body cylinder with a active rigid body gear with "G move", but when I try in the blender 2.8.3 the cylinder doesn't collides with the gear when I move the cylinder during the simulation.

My setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for updating. I'll delete my previous answer and post a new one if I figure it out.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I get a crash sometimes when I tried, see: https://developer.blender.org/T78868, you too?